# Can I setup something like Cloudflare's Argo between a VPS and a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I have an AWS Lightsail server and I want to setup something like Cloudflare's Argo Tunnel between my server and a Raspberry Pi on my home LAN. Is there any existing software that allows me to do that? Something using SSH maybe?

All I have been able to find till now is GRE Tunnels which are impossible for me to setup.

Clarification: I'm not talking about Argo's DDOS protection, I just want to be able to serve things off my RPi without having to setup inbound ports and DDNS.

Comment: I can do a full write-up later- does if work if you do a forward or reverse tunnel SSH pi->server?  Is this one port or a set of ports? TCP/UDP?